# How do I access Array value from another plugin in wordpress?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I need to get the value of an array from $response

```
if(isset($post_args['response_bypass'])) {
            $response = $post_args['response_bypass'];
        }
```

The code is from forms-3rdparty-integration.php on line 490

https://github.com/zaus/forms-3rdparty-integration/blob/master/forms-3rdparty-integration.php

and I want to pass that value to another plugin, in this case is contact form 7 on this file

https://github.com/wp-plugins/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/submission.php

My goal is to get the response value from the 3rd party integration plugin and check if its the response I want then submit email if not then show the error message  that came from response after clicking submit button

Answer (score 0):

Use of global array except local array.
e.g.

$response {
......
}

except:
function() $response{
....
}

I think you should look at your files `functions.php` and search about `$response` to make it global array.